# Passing POST type of parameter and receiving it on another page in AEM/CQ5

Tags: jsp, servlets, post, aem

I have created webpage in AEM having login functionality (username and password) and I need to pass these 2 paramaters using POST method. I am able to do the same using GET but when I try with POST, I get error stating that Content is modified/created.

I am passing the parameters using html `<form action="destination.html" method="POST">`

I read that I need to create a Sling Servlet which will manage my POST method. But the question is how to do so? and where to create that servlet file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same servlet and override the doPost method.

```
@SlingServlet(
methods = { "POST","GET" }, 
name="com.tti.tticommons.service.servlets.LeadTimeTrendsServlet",
paths = { "/services/processFormData" }
)
public class CommonServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet{   
...
@Override
protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request,SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException {
....
}
```

I have listed an example here [AEM 6.1 Sightly basic form submit and redirect to same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31454357/aem-6-1-sightly-basic-form-submit-and-redirect-to-same-page/31483005#31483005)

Comment: Thanks Surendra, but can you please tell me where to add this java servlet file whether in CRXDE or in a Java Project uploaded as a bundle in AME??

Comment: I always use java project as part of your core package / bundle.